# Google Places API natural_feature

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api

I use the google places api autocomplete to save location, state and country from the hotels users of my web.

For example
The search of Alcúdia, Illes Balears, Espanya returns me:

- administrative_area_level_4:Alcudia
- administrative_area_level_3:Raiguer
- administrative_area_level_2:Islas Baleares
- administrative_area_level_1:Islas Baleares
- country:España

I store this data in my DB.

In my market web if I search hotels by those fields everything's fine but if I searh by 'natural_feature', I don't have enough data to match the places.

The search of 'Mallorca' returns me:

- natural_feature: Mallorca
- administrative_area_level_2: Islas Baleares
- administrative_area_level_1: Islas Baleares
- country:España

And the search of 'Menorca' returns me:

- natural_feature: Menorca
- administrative_area_level_2: Islas Baleares
- administrative_area_level_1: Islas Baleares
- country:España

Both are in the same administrative_area_level but they are different islands, so when I'm trying to know in which query should I match the hotels, some data is missing.